# iframe doesn't get updated after the upload 'AJAX' upload trick

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the iframe technique to upload a file contained in a form.

It's working perfectly, I even send myself an email with the file. The only problem is that I want to get infos from the iframe, such as file size. However, I can't update the iframe's content from the php script. I tried putting 'echos' on the line before it sends the email (so it actually gets there), but as soon as the iframe's jQuery's "load" function fires, there is nothing in the iframe. Even tried "Inspect element" and "view source", all empty.

Am I missing something obvious? I can't find anyone with the same problem on SO or google.

FORM:

```
<form id="submitResumeForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="career/sendResume" target="submitTarget">
<!-- input fields, etc -->
<input type="button" onClick="submitForm()" value="<?=lang('submit')?>" />
</form>
<iframe id="submitTarget" name="submitTarget" src="" style="position:absolute;top:-1000px;left:-1000px;width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function submitForm()
{
    $('#submitResumeForm').attr('target', 'submitTarget');
    // ... verifications ...
    $('#submitTarget').load(function()
    {
        console.log( $(this).html() ); // Content is: "content before"
        console.log( $(this).contents() ); //Garbage
    });
    // Line Below puts content in the iframe, and that content is still there after
    // the php is executed, so iframe is NEVER updated
    $('#submitTarget').html('content before');

    $("#submitResumeForm").submit();
}
```

PHP CONTROLLER:

```
function sendResume()
{
    echo 'ASDFASDFASDFASDF';
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->clear();      
    $this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));
    // ... other fields, attach file (working perfectly)
    $this->email->send();
}
```

Comment: Looks like the request to load iframe's content is blocked by something on the server and does not return the HTML. There are couple of places things might go wrong. More information is needed to answer this question. But please, read this question/answer, it should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034987/ajax-file-upload-with-iframe-returning-and-using-the-filename-for-additional-a

Comment: I checked the link in stackoverflow, but there is nothing I didn't try on the answers.
I know it would be better with all the code, but it's using the codeigniter framework so you would need the whole application to test. Anyway, I will post what I can, if anyone knows CI, feel free to see what you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:
The line

```
console.log( $('#submitTarget').html() ); // Display iframe's content
```

Is NOT updated in the DOM for some reason I don't know, you have to use this if this ever happens to you:

```
console.log( $('#submitTarget').contents().find('body').html() );
```

Comment: The `<iframe>`'s contents in the DOM are whatever appears within the actual `<iframe>...</iframe>` tags. This is meant to used as a fallback for when frames aren't supported, but is usually omitted. The jQuery `.contents()` function treats `<iframes>` as a special case, and returns the document inside of the frame element. In other cases it would return the contents of the element itself (which are still part of the current document).

Answer (score 0):

i think you are doing it wrong...
what you should do is something like

```
<form ...>
   <input type="file" .../>
   <input type="submit" .../>
</form>
<iframe id="myIframe"></iframe>

$('form').submit(function(){
   $(form).attr('target'. 'myIframe');
});
```

I don't know if this will work, but i remember a long time ago i tried it somehow as you are doing it and i had to change it to the way i do today.
Just for kicks, can you try to change the input-button to an input-submit removing the onclick and putting the code inside your submitForm() function into the submit event of the form as i do above (removing your last line invoking submit() and $('#submitTarget').load(function() and  $('#submitTarget').html('content before');)?

you just need to change the target, really

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm doing, tried setting the target manually directly in the the form tag as well, no change.

Besides, if it's uploading the file and sending it via email, it means the target was set accordingly.

Comment: Done, it's in the original question

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, tried it, no change, it's also sending the email with the attachment but still the old content is in the frame.

Comment: can you have a look at http://andrepadez.com/testupload/ ?  view source, it's all there, and it's working

Comment: Damn, tried your example, it's not working either! So I tried it in Chrome and it works, so does my code, the problem is Opera browser.

Comment: oh, ok... that makes sense. But this works in IE and FF to, i only test it on these three, usually

Comment: I'm trying to get around the opera problem and post the solution here for future references. Thanks for your time though!